# "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: sendEmail.handler is undefined or not exported" I get this error .can anoyone tell how to resolve it

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SES = new AWS.SES();

const FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS = process.env.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
const TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS = process.env.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS;

function sendEmailToMe(formData) {

```
const emailParams = {
    Source: FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
    ReplyToAddresses: [TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS],
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS], 
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: `Thanks for subscription: ${formData.message}\n\n Name: ${formData.name}\n Email: ${formData.email}\n I will reply as soon as possible`,
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: 'New message from your_site.com',
      },
    },
};

console.log(emailParams)

const promise =  SES.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();
console.log(promise);
return promise
```

}

exports.sendEmail = async(event) => {
console.log('Send email called');

```
const dynamodb = event.Records[0].dynamodb;
console.log(dynamodb);

const formData = {
    name : dynamodb.NewImage.name.S,
    message : dynamodb.NewImage.message.S,
    email : dynamodb.NewImage.email.S
}
console.log(formData);

return sendEmailToMe(formData).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You specified that the entrance function for your lambda is called `handler`. There is no `handler` function in your code though. Thats why you get this runtime error.

Comment: The function that should run in your lambda has to be called handler.

Comment: Thank you, i changed it ,But this error came.. "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: This is another problem. It seems like your event doesn't have a property 'Records'.

Comment: If that answer helped you, would you be so kind to accept it?